# How to find all that don't belong to a specific id in belongsToMany?

Tags: sequelize.js, feathersjs, sequelize-typescript, feathers-sequelize

I have the following models:

```js
const users = sequelize.define('users', { /* definition */ }
const messageGroups = sequelize.define('message_groups', { /* definition */ }
```

They are associated like this:

```js
models.messageGroups.belongsToMany(models.users, {through: 'user_message_groups'})
models.users.belongsToMany(models.messageGroups, {through: 'user_message_groups'})
```

How can I return a list of users that are not in a messageGroup with a specific id?

For example, let's say my tables look like this

users

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo |
| 2 | Bar |
| 3 | Baz |

message_groups

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin |
| 2 | Users |

user_message_groups

| userId | messageGroupId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

Given a message_groups id of 1 (Admin), how can I construct a query that returns the two users that are **not** in that message_group? (Should return users `Bar` and `Baz`)

Comment: Which do you pass as a variable, 1 or Admin?

Comment: The `message_groups.id` which, in the example, is `1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing id as a variable, one option is to use just `users` and `user_message_groups` table.

First, you need a model definition for `user_message_groups`.

```
const userMessageGroups = sequelize.define('user_message_groups', {
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    messageGroupId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
});
```

Next, create an association between users and user_message_groups table.

```
models.users.hasMany(models.userMessageGroups);
```

Then query with exclusive LEFT JOIN.

```
models.users.findAll({
    include: {
        model: models.userMessageGroups,
        required: false,
        where: {
            messageGroupId: 1
        }
    },
    where: models.sequelize.literal('`user_message_groups.messageGroupId` IS NULL')
});
```